# How do you fill the view in a custom alert dialog?

Tags: android

When I take a snapshot of the custom dialog using the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/multi_select"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>
```

[note: with my given xml i realize the textview set to gone, but i manually set it to visible later]

Below the custom textview (no list) or single item listview, there's a gray margin which according the XML snapshot belongs to the framelayout from alert_dialog.xml: android.R.id.customPanel, which I don't have access to.
How do I fill in that view to be white?

It seems like my view height less than the min height of the custom dialog view.

[image: alert dialog with gray below.]

Comment: Hi, I suggest you open it in a new Activity with a Dialog theme

Comment: Please elaborate more?

Comment: please show you java code

Comment: i think you need to display custom dialog with transparent background ? put your exact screen shot you need it.